Multiple for groups / let reduce aggregations with ABAP 7.57
I have a raw dataset  that looks like this:

that I need to convert to looking like that for today, which is 18.12.2024:

It is in essentialy pivoting.
So far I managed to create the dynamic table type of the output table using RTTS and now need to find a way to populate it from the raw data.
The base logic is sumarization of quanitity based on date, werks and land:
_t0 column is sum for the day if wadat = erdat,
_older is sum of the day if erdat is more than a day older than current day
ABC is the sum of the day for all where ABC exists in ZUKRL
So far I am only able to sum based on simple group by:
  t_data = VALUE #( FOR GROUPS g1 OF ls_row IN gt_data GROUP BY ( wadat = ls_row-wadat
                                                                  werks = ls_row-werks
                                                                  land1 = ls_row-land1
                                                                  "erdat = ls_row-erdat
                                                               )
                     LET sum = REDUCE #( INIT line TYPE ty_sum_line
                                         FOR members_g1 IN GROUP g1
                                         NEXT line-wadat = members_g1-wadat
                                              line-werks = members_g1-werks
                                              line-land1 = members_g1-land1
                                              line-lfimg = line-lfimg + members_g1-lfimg
                                        )
                  IN ( wadat = g1-wadat
                       werks = g1-werks
                       land1 = g1-land1
                       lfimg = sum-lfimg
                       "lfimg_t0
                       "lfimg_older
                       "lfimg_abc
                      )
                   ).

My idea is to fill lfimg_t0 lfimg_older lfimg_abc with the appropriate sums and then loop and populate the dynamic table. Could you help me out with the grouping logic, please.
Added for clarification after comments:
How to get values from group g_tot into  these:
"lfimg_t0
"lfimg_older
"lfimg_abc
    t_data2 = VALUE #( FOR GROUPS g1 OF ls_row IN gt_data GROUP BY ( wadat = ls_row-wadat
                                                                 werks = ls_row-werks
                                                                 land1 = ls_row-land1
                                                                )
                   FOR GROUPS g_tot OF row_tot IN gt_data GROUP BY ( wadat = row_tot-wadat
                                                                     werks = row_tot-werks
                                                                )
                      LET sum = REDUCE #( INIT line TYPE ty_sum_line
                                         FOR members_g1 IN GROUP g1
                                         NEXT line-wadat = members_g1-wadat
                                              line-werks = members_g1-werks
                                              line-land1 = members_g1-land1
                                              line-lfimg = line-lfimg + members_g1-lfimg
                                        )
                  IN ( wadat = g1-wadat
                       werks = g1-werks
                       land1 = g1-land1
                       lfimg = sum-lfimg
                       "lfimg_t0
                       "lfimg_older
                       "lfimg_abc
                      )
                   ).

... And I am thinking I need a field to store what group is this coming from in order to be able to populate the result table, because there are many different WERKS with even more LAND1

Good idea to have LET sum = in order to loop only once at the lines of each group. In complement to line-lfimg, you should calculate line-lfimg_t0 and the others. Not complex e.g. line-lfimg_t0 = line-lfimg_t0 + COND #( when members_gl-wadat = members_gl-erdat THEN members_g1-lfimg ). Did you miss COND?

Populating the dynamic table is a question completely different, please ask another question. Stack Overflow is not to solve one requirement but one question. See the Help Center how to formulate the questions.

Populating the dynamic table is clear (not asking about this). Using COND is very good hint, thank you. Unfortunately I may have be unclear about the groupings. I have group by WADAT, WERKS and LAND1, but I also need grouping only by WADAT and WERKS for the totals.

Here's one way, but the code is quite complex, it will be easier to understand if you split it into method(s).
It compiles in ABAP 7.40 SP8.
DATA(intermediate_lines) = VALUE intermediate_lines(
    FOR GROUPS <group_by_wadat_werks> OF <source_line> IN source_lines
    GROUP BY ( wadat = <source_line>-wadat
               werks = <source_line>-werks )
    LET sums_by_wadat_werks_land1 = VALUE intermediate_lines(
                FOR GROUPS <group_by_land1>
                OF <source_line_2> IN GROUP <group_by_wadat_werks>
                GROUP BY ( land1 = <source_line_2>-land1 )
                LET sums = REDUCE sums(
                     INIT sums_2 TYPE sums
                     FOR <line_of_group_by_land1> IN GROUP <group_by_land1>
                     NEXT sums_2-lfimg = sums_2-lfimg
                                         + <line_of_group_by_land1>-lfimg )
                IN
                    ( wadat = <group_by_wadat_werks>-wadat
                      werks = <group_by_wadat_werks>-werks
                      land1 = <group_by_land1>-land1
                      lfimg = sums-lfimg ) )
        sums_by_wadat_werks       = VALUE intermediate_line(
                LET sums_3 = REDUCE sums(
                     INIT sums_2 TYPE sums
                     FOR <line_sums_by_wadat_werks_lan> IN sums_by_wadat_werks_land1
                     NEXT sums_2-lfimg = sums_2-lfimg
                                         + <line_sums_by_wadat_werks_lan>-lfimg )
                IN  wadat = <group_by_wadat_werks>-wadat
                    werks = <group_by_wadat_werks>-werks
                    land1 = 'TOT'
                    lfimg = sums_3-lfimg )
    IN
        ( LINES OF sums_by_wadat_werks_land1 )
        ( sums_by_wadat_werks ) ).

Code before the block above, containing the test data (require declarations described below):
DATA(source_lines) = VALUE source_lines( werks = 'DE10'
                                         lfimg = 1
                                         ( wadat = '20241217' land1 = 'DE' )
                                         ( wadat = '20241217' land1 = 'DE' )
                                         ( wadat = '20241217' land1 = 'FR' )
                                         ( wadat = '20241218' land1 = 'DE' ) ).

Code after the block above, to check the result (it's the expected result):
ASSERT intermediate_lines = VALUE intermediate_lines(
    werks = 'DE10'
    ( wadat = '20241217' land1 = 'DE'  lfimg = 2 )
    ( wadat = '20241217' land1 = 'FR'  lfimg = 1 )
    ( wadat = '20241217' land1 = 'TOT' lfimg = 3 )
    ( wadat = '20241218' land1 = 'DE'  lfimg = 1 )
    ( wadat = '20241218' land1 = 'TOT' lfimg = 1 ) ).

Declarations, to be placed first:
TYPES lfimg TYPE p LENGTH 7 DECIMALS 2.
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF source_line,
    wadat TYPE d,
    werks TYPE c LENGTH 4,
    land1 TYPE land1,
    lfimg TYPE lfimg,
  END OF source_line.
TYPES source_lines TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF source_line WITH EMPTY KEY.
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF intermediate_line,
    wadat TYPE d,
    werks TYPE c LENGTH 4,
    land1 TYPE land1,
    lfimg TYPE lfimg,
  END OF intermediate_line.
TYPES intermediate_lines TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF intermediate_line WITH EMPTY KEY.
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF sums,
    lfimg TYPE lfimg,
  END OF sums.

